# Is it possible using c# to set and change the X & Y offsets of a Zebra label Printer?

Tags: c#, printing, zebra-printers

I have been researching this for some time now and cannot find a definitive way of doing this.

Here is the problem:
My company has to change the size of the labels they print for different products. When they do this, they calibrate the printers for the new label and find that the label design printed is mis-aligned.

I want to implement a alignment tool which non-technical users can use to quickly get the alignment correct.

However, i have had no success in finding any API or functions that will allow me to mimic the Page properties for a specific printer and allow me to set and save an offset value.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was much easier than i had anticipated.

The current Label software we are using (NiceLabel 4) allows us to perform functions such as change the offsets and change the darkness, speed, etc. 
The issue i was having was that in the version we are using it seems to be flawed.

I tried upgrading to NiceLabel 6 and the new extension that it provides resolves these issue.

I can now use my tool to work out the offset values and i can store them whilst a product is being processed. It also provides handy functions to set the darkness, speed and rotation.